# rich:inputNumberSpinner mousewheel disable

Tags: richfaces, mousewheel

How do I disable rich:inputNumberSpinner value changing by mousewheel on the Google Chrome browser? On Mozilla Firefox it disabled by default (you can check it on http://tinyurl.com/po78uko)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't support the `mousewheel` event, that's why it doesn't work there.

Anyway, you can disable it with this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        #{rich:component('spinnerId')}.input.unbind('mousewheel');
    });
</script>
```